# Devexpress how get index row in ComboBox DataBinding method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

```
<dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="<%$Resources: zione%>" Width="15%" Visible="true">                                
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="comboZione" 
                      runat="server" 
                      ValueField="TIPB_CTBZIONE"
                      TextField="DEFI_CTBZIONE" 
                      OnDataBinding="comboZione_OnDataBinding" 
                      EnableCallbackMode="false" 
                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="combo_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
```

In Code behind:

```
protected void comboZione_OnDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxComboBox cmb = (sender as ASPxComboBox);
    cmb.DataSource = ddlLoadZione(IndexRow);
    // Here I want to bind the different combox on which row, 
    // but I needed a index row to do this. 
}
```

Index row needed me to get right value of the row.

```
Grid.GetRowValues(**IndexRow**, "FieldName")
```

Comment: You should probably ask on the DevExpress support directly, only people that work there have any chance of understanding how to do anything with DevExpress... it's such a painful library to work with. Also, your question isn't very clear anyway

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task, I suggest you use the approach described in the [The general technique of using the Init/Load event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18282.aspx) article and set the combobox' DataSource property in its Init event handler.

I believe it is possible to:

1. Handle the ASPxComboBox.Init event;
2. Provide the ASPxComboBox.DataSource based on your custom conditions (row values, etc.).

**Refer these:**
[ASPxGridView - Bind ASPxComboBox placed in DataItemTemplate](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q452637/aspxgridview-bind-aspxcombobox-placed-in-dataitemtemplate)
[ASPxGridView - How to bind controls placed in the DataItemTemplate with the data field of the grid row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q335674/aspxgridview-how-to-bind-controls-placed-in-the-dataitemtemplate-with-the-data-field-of)
[ASPxComboBox on each line / DataItemTemplate of ASPxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q444457/aspxcombobox-on-each-line-dataitemtemplate-of-aspxgridview)
[ASPxGridView - How to bind ASPxComboBox in the data item template](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T372377/aspxgridview-how-to-bind-aspxcombobox-in-the-data-item-template)